# subset an additional variable and append it to the previous one in R

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe, subset

I have a function that `subset`s `what` (i.e., a variable) user requests out of  [**this dataset**](https://github.com/izeh/i/blob/master/k.csv).

The function works perfect. But I was wondering if there might be a way that **in addition to** `what` user requests, the function always `subset` entries that contain `control == TRUE` and append those to `what` the user has requested.

For example, suppose user wants to subset entries with `type == 4`. In [**this dataset**](https://github.com/izeh/i/blob/master/k.csv), there are **4** such entries. As **reproducible code and data below** show, this is done easily **BUT** there also are **4** other entries for which `control == TRUE`, how can function find and append these **4** other entries to its *currently-producible* output?

```
foo <- function(List, what){       ## The subsetting function

  s <- substitute(what) 

  h <- lapply(List, function(x) do.call("subset", list(x, s)))

  Filter(NROW, h)
}


D <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/i/master/k.csv", h = T) ## Dataset
L <- split(D, D$study.name) ; L[[1]] <- NULL   ## list by `study.name`

foo(L, type == 4)    ## subsets entries with `type == 4`. BUT how can function `foo` 
                     ## find and append entries with `control == TRUE` to its output?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `Filter`ing the `list` elements ('h1'), `subset` those same elements from the original `list` where the 'control' is TRUE (logical column) and theen `rbind` the corresponding `list` elements with `Map`

```
foo <- function(List, what){     
   s <- substitute(what) 
   h <- lapply(List, function(x) do.call("subset", list(x, s)))
   h1 <- Filter(NROW, h)      
   h2 <- lapply(List[names(h1)], function(x) subset(x, control))
   Map(rbind, h1, h2)      
}


foo(L, type == 4)
#$Mubarak
#   study.name  group.name  n  d t.pair df mdif sdif  mpre sdpre  mpos sdpos      r rev.sign autoreg post control outcome ESL prof
#43    Mubarak   grA.short 17 NA  4.366 NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    FALSE   FALSE    1   FALSE       1   2   NA
#44    Mubarak    grA.long 17 NA     NA NA   NA   NA 0.395 0.280 0.520 0.205 0.6737    FALSE   FALSE    2   FALSE       1   2   NA
#54    Mubarak  grB.shortB 16 NA  7.864 NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     TRUE   FALSE    1   FALSE       2   2   NA
#55    Mubarak   grB.longB 16 NA     NA NA   NA   NA 0.105 0.030 0.056 0.025 0.5618     TRUE   FALSE    2   FALSE       2   2   NA
#47    Mubarak  Cont.short 13 NA  0.401 NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    FALSE   FALSE    1    TRUE       1   2   NA
#48    Mubarak   Cont.long 13 NA     NA NA   NA   NA 0.545 0.272 0.436 0.204 0.5320    FALSE   FALSE    2    TRUE       1   2   NA
#49    Mubarak  Cont.short 13 NA  0.401 NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    FALSE   FALSE    1    TRUE       1   2   NA
#50    Mubarak   Cont.long 13 NA     NA NA   NA   NA 0.545 0.272 0.436 0.204 0.5320    FALSE   FALSE    2    TRUE       1   2   NA
#56    Mubarak Cont.shortB 13 NA  2.793 NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     TRUE   FALSE    1    TRUE       2   2   NA
#57    Mubarak  Cont.longB 13 NA     NA NA   NA   NA 0.093 0.032 0.078 0.032 0.9159     TRUE   FALSE    2    TRUE       2   2   NA
#   scope type
#43     2    4
#44     2    4
#54     2    4
#55     2    4
#47     2    2
#48     2    2
#49     2    2
#50     2    2
#56     2    2
#57     2    2
```

Comment: `foo` is already doing that! Please read again, you''ll find out what the problem is.

Comment: Just as safety net, can we use `Filter` after `h2` in case it might be empty?

Comment: @rnorouzian  We already used `Filter` at 'h1' .  Here, even if it empty, the `rbind` should take care of it.  Let me know if there is any issues

Comment: @rnorouzian  Let's say if 'h1' is empty, then you don't need to evaluate the codes that are below right?  In that case, `if(length(h1) > 0) {h2 <- lapply(List[names(h1)], function(x) subset(x, control));  Map(rbind, h1, h2) } else h1}`

Comment: Hi Arun, hope all is going well. Can you possibly help with [**This Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57118322/modify-and-recreate-a-list-of-data-frame-in-r) from a kind friend of mine?

Comment: @rnorouzian  i did comment on his previous question with a list of data.frames.  He is using the same code on a list of vectors.

Comment: thanks, she is new in here, and has a bit of language barrier. I appreciate your help. I just edited her comments.

Comment: @Reza Okay, if you can simplify it, please do so

Comment: @Reza Can you post as a new question as this question already have lots of comments

Comment: Here is the [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58739159/conditionally-subset-an-additional-variable-and-append-it-to-the-previous-one-in)?