# Modify and recreate a list of data.frame in R

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe, lapply

I have a `list` of `data.frame`s called `m` (see [**HERE**](https://github.com/izeh/m/blob/master/g.csv)). Column `r` in these data.frames is all `NA`.

But later on, I have computed some of these `r`s and stored them as a list called `L`.

**I'm wondering how to achieve the following?:**

(1) If any list entry in `L` (i.e., `L[[1]]`, `L[[2]]`, ...), starts with a number BUT right after it is `NA`, replace `NA` with that number.

(2) Put back all new `r`s (stored in `L`) in column `r`, in the original list of data.frames `m`.

```
D <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/m/master/g.csv", h = T) ## Data


m <- split(D, D$study.name) ;  m[[1]] <- NULL  ## original list of data.frame    
                                               ## To be finally recreated.


 L <- list(Bit.KnoA = rep(NA, 8), Bit.KnoB = rep(NA, 12), ChandlerA = c(.5, .5), 
Mubarak = c(.6, NA, .5, NA, .5, NA, .8, NA, .5,NA,.9,NA), SheenA = rep(NA, 6),
Shin.Ellis = rep(NA, 6), Sun = rep(NA, 6), Trus.Hsu = rep(NA, 2))


lapply(L, transform, r = zoo::na.locf0(r)) ## To achieve (1), but Not working !


###### NOW, put back L in the new list of data.frame like `m` above? ######
```

Comment: i think this is based on your earliere question with regard to list of data.frame.  The code I suggested was for that.  here, L is a list of vectors `lapply(L, na.locf0)`

Comment: @rnorouzian  As I mentioned, the output and input is a list of vectors.  So, I am not sure what she expects.  If the inteention is to creaete a data.frame with one column, `lapply(L, function(x) data.frame(r = na.locf0(x)))`

Comment: IN that case, it is `Map(function(x, y) transform(x, r = na.locf0(y)), m, L)`

Comment: @rnorouzian  Thank you.  Glad to know that it is helping for her cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the intention is to replace the 'r' column in the `list` of `data.frame` in 'm' with the corresponding 'L' `list` of `vectors` applied with `na.locf0`, then

```
library(zoo)
m1 <- Map(function(x, y) transform(x, r = na.locf0(y)), m, L)
```

Comment: I really consider you my unseen "friend". May God give you good health.

Comment: @rnorouzian  Thank you friend. I wish the same to you

Comment: Oh btw, just curious how exactly `na.locf0` fills the `NA`s, I mean in what order? Is it using the next number or previous number or what?

Comment: Maybe first we should first use `na.locf0(fromLast = T)` and then, `na.locf0(fromLast = F)` so to make sure all possible `NA`s are filled out, then use `Map`, right?

Comment: Hi Arun, could [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57383680/subtracting-similarly-named-elements-in-a-list-of-vectors-in-r) be possibly of interest to you?

Comment: @Reza It is certainly of interest, but ssome people already answered it