# Subtracting similarly named elements in a list of vectors in R

Tags: r, list, function, lapply

I have a list of 3 vectors, `X`, `Y`, and `Z`. I want to subtract **similarly named** elements of these 3 vectors. That is, similarly named elements subtracted throughout like so: `X - Y - Z`.

Also, if an element (here `ChandlerA` and `Trus.Hsu` in `X`) appears only once in one vector but not in others, then I want to skip that element altogether.

My **desired output** is:

`c(Bit.KnoA = -2, Bit.KnoB = -4, Bit.KnoC = -2, Ellis.etal = 3, Mubarak = 3, sheenA = 5, Shin.Ellis = 5, Sun = 7)`

Is it possible to achieve this in **Base R**?

```
V = list(X = c(Bit.KnoA = 4, Bit.KnoB = 1, Bit.KnoC = 2, ChandlerA = 3, Ellis.etal =4, 
               Mubarak=5, SheenA=6,  Shin.Ellis=7 , Sun = 8, Trus.Hsu=3 ), 

         Y = c(Bit.KnoA = 6, Bit.KnoB = 3, Bit.KnoC = 4, Ellis.etal =1, Mubarak=2, 
               SheenA=1,  Shin.Ellis=2 , Sun = 1),

         Z = c(Bit.KnoB = 2) )



V[[1]] - V[[2]] - V[[3]] # all elements regardless of names are subtracted
```

Comment: Something like that `i = intersect(names(V$X), intersect(names(V$Y), names(V$Z))); V$X[i] - (V$Y[i] + V$Z[i])`?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: I would do it in a 3 step approach:
1. Change list to dataframe X,Y,Z
2. Inner join based on name
3. do the substraction.

Comment: @utubun For example, `Bit.KnoA` appears in `X` and `Y`, so   `Bit.KnoA` in `X` -  `Bit.KnoA` in `Y`. Or `Bit.KnoB` appears in `X`, `Y` and `Z`, so `Bit.KnoB` in `X` - `Bit.KnoB` in `Y` - `Bit.KnoB` in `Z`. But `ChandlerA` only appears in `X` so exclude that altogether.

Comment: @Koot6133, could you possibly demonstrate your approach?

Comment: And you want original list with changed 'X"?

Comment: @utubun, I have added my desired output.

Comment: `Bit.KnoB` must be `-4`, no?

Comment: What about that: `l = sapply(names(V$X), function(i) sum(V$X[i], -V$Y[i], -V$Z[i], na.rm = T));
l[l != V$X]` It doesn't work correctly, though if `V$Y` and `V$Z` have zero entries with the same names as in `V$X`

Comment: @utubun, I'm not sure what you exactly mean by *"It doesn't work correctly, though if V$Y and V$Z have zero entries with the same names as in V$X"*? Specially, what does *zero entries with the same names as in V$X* mean?

Comment: Imagine that there are elements with names 'foo' in `X`, `Y` and `Z`, and imaging that `(Y$foo == 0 & Z$foo == 0) | (Y$foo == -Z$foo)`. In this case, if `X$foo` e.g. 5 the answer is 5, but with the last line `l[l != V$X]` you filter it out from the output.

Comment: @utubun, oh I see, I'm sure there should be a way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this more compactly with `aggregate` and `Reduce`

```
with(aggregate(values ~ ind, subset(do.call(rbind, lapply(V, stack)), 
    ind %in% names(which(table(ind) > 1))), 
     FUN = function(x) Reduce(`-`, x)), setNames(values, ind))
#   Bit.KnoA   Bit.KnoB   Bit.KnoC Ellis.etal    Mubarak     SheenA Shin.Ellis        Sun 
#        -2         -4         -2          3          3          5          5          7
```

---

or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
map_df(V, enframe) %>% 
     group_by(name) %>% 
     filter(n() > 1) %>% 
     summarise(value = reduce(value, `-`)) %>%
     deframe
#   Bit.KnoA   Bit.KnoB   Bit.KnoC Ellis.etal    Mubarak     SheenA Shin.Ellis        Sun 
#        -2         -4         -2          3          3          5          5          7
```

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58309964/separate-columns-with-constant-numbers-and-condense-them-into-one-row-in-r-data) may be interesting to you?

Comment: @Reza Let me know when you would be online for the doubt clearance

Answer (score 1):

Here is one base R option

```
#Copy contents of V
V1 <- V
#Remove names of V1
names(V1) <- NULL
#unlist the values
vals <- unlist(V1)
#Find out names which occur only once
delete_names <- names(Filter(function(x) x == 1, table(names(vals))))
#Remove them from the list
new_vals <- vals[!names(vals) %in% delete_names]
#Subtract values from each similar named element.
sapply(unique(names(new_vals)), function(x) Reduce(`-`, new_vals[names(new_vals) == x]))

# Bit.KnoA   Bit.KnoB   Bit.KnoC Ellis.etal    Mubarak     SheenA Shin.Ellis        Sun 
#       -2         -4         -2          3          3          5          5          7
```