# Separate columns with constant numbers and condense them to one row in R data.frame

Tags: r, function, loops, dataframe

I have a data.frame called `d`. In this data.frame, some columns consist of constant numbers across the rows of the first column: `study.name` (see below).

For example, columns `ESL`, `ESL.1`, `prof`, and `prof.1` are constant numbers for all rows of `Shin.Ellis` and also constant for all rows of `Trus.Hsu` and so on.

**Q:** **In BASE R**, how can I separate such constant variables, and then condense them to one row with only one number?

**My desired output** is shown further below. A functional answer is appreciated.

```
d <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/m/master/irr.csv", h = T)[-(2:3)]

## FIRST 8 ROWS:

#    study.name ESL prof scope type ESL.1 prof.1 scope.1 type.1
# 1  Shin.Ellis   1    2     1    1     1      2       1      1
# 2  Shin.Ellis   1    2     1    1     1      2       1      1
# 3  Shin.Ellis   1    2     1    2     1      2       1      1
# 4  Shin.Ellis   1    2     1    2     1      2       1      1
# 5  Shin.Ellis   1    2    NA   NA     1      2      NA     NA
# 6  Shin.Ellis   1    2    NA   NA     1      2      NA     NA
# 7    Trus.Hsu   2    2     2    1     2      2       1      1
# 8    Trus.Hsu   2    2    NA   NA     2      2      NA     NA
```

**Desired output:**

```
#    study.name ESL prof  ESL.1 prof.1 
# 1  Shin.Ellis   1    2      1      2  
# 2  Trus.Hsu     2    2      2      2
# .     .         .    .      .      . # AND SO ON !!!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be we need

```
library(dplyr)
d %>%
   group_by(study.name) %>%
   slice(1)
```

---

Or in `base R` after grouping by 'study.name', get the first row while specifying the `na.action = NULL` as the default option is `na.omit` which can omit any row having `NA` in any of the columns

```
aggregate(.~ study.name, d, head, 1, na.action = NULL)
```

If we want to subset the columns

```
nm1 <- names(which(!colSums(!do.call(rbind, by(d[-1], d$study.name,
     FUN = function(x) lengths(sapply(x, unique)) == 1)))))
unique(d[c("study.name", nm1)])
```

Comment: Doesn't this just get the first row without NAs? It will not restrict to columns that were constant for each group

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to remove repeated values across all columns unique() is base R

```
unique(d)
```

EDIT - Thanks for the clarification @CalumYou - I think this is what OP is looking for in base R.

```
is_constant = lapply(split(d, d$study.name), function(data){
  unlist(lapply(data,function(col){
    length(unique(col)) == 1
  }))
})
is_constant = as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, is_constant))
all_constant = d[,unlist(lapply(is_constant,all))]
all_constant = unique(all_constant)
```

Comment: It seems like that is not the OP's question, they want to figure out which columns are constant by group, for all groups

Comment: @CalumYou, Thank you for your answer. That's exactly what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

```
d_list <- lapply(split(d,d$study.name), 
                 #Find columns with similar values using sapply and length(unique(cols)) 
                 #then get the 1st row
                 function(x) x[1, sapply(x,function(y) length(unique(y))==1)])
do.call('rbind.data.frame',d_list)

           study.name ESL prof ESL.1 prof.1
Bit.KnoA     Bit.KnoA   1    3     1      3
Bit.KnoB     Bit.KnoB   1    2     1      2
ChandlerA   ChandlerA   1    2     1      2
Mubarak       Mubarak   2   NA     2     NA
SheenA         SheenA   1    2     1      2
Shin.Ellis Shin.Ellis   1    2     1      2
Sun               Sun   2    2     2      2
Trus.Hsu     Trus.Hsu   2    2     2      2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, though it feels a bit clumsy. Basically, check which columns have constant values by group for all groups, keep only those columns, and then keep only `unique` values (since now they are constant by group).

```r
d <- read.table(header = TRUE,
text = "study.name ESL prof scope type ESL.1 prof.1 scope.1 type.1
Shin.Ellis   1    2     1    1     1      2       1      1
Shin.Ellis   1    2     1    1     1      2       1      1
Shin.Ellis   1    2     1    2     1      2       1      1
Shin.Ellis   1    2     1    2     1      2       1      1
Shin.Ellis   1    2    NA   NA     1      2      NA     NA
Shin.Ellis   1    2    NA   NA     1      2      NA     NA
  Trus.Hsu   2    2     2    1     2      2       1      1
  Trus.Hsu   2    2    NA   NA     2      2      NA     NA")

is_constant <- function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1L

keep_constants <- function(df, group_col) {
  data_cols <- colnames(df)[setdiff(1:ncol(df), group_col)]
  check_df <- aggregate(df, by = list(df[[group_col]]), FUN = is_constant)
  cols_to_keep <- sapply(check_df[, -1], all)
  unique(df[, cols_to_keep])
}

keep_constants(d, 1)
#>   study.name ESL prof ESL.1 prof.1
#> 1 Shin.Ellis   1    2     1      2
#> 7   Trus.Hsu   2    2     2      2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>