# conditionally subset an additional variable and append it to the previous one in R

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe, subset

I'm following up on this **[excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57024848/8840683)**. I have a function that `subset`s `what` (i.e., a variable) user requests out of  [**this dataset**](https://github.com/rnorouzian/m/blob/master/k.csv).

I was wondering how to add `control == TRUE` entries **IF THEY ARE ABSENT** in the output and append those to `what` the user has requested, otherwise don't do anything.

As an example of `control == T` absent, suppose user wants to subset entries with `type == 4`. In [**this dataset**](https://github.com/rnorouzian/m/blob/master/k.csv), there are some such entries. As **reproducible code and data below** show, this is done easily **BUT** there also are some other entries for which `control == TRUE`, how can function find and append these `control == TRUE` entries to its *currently-producible* output?

As an example of `control == T` present, suppose user wants to subset entries with `prof == 2`. In this case `control == T` entries naturally come with the subset and don't need to be added. So don't do anything.

```
foo <- function(List, what){       ## The subsetting function

  s <- substitute(what) 

  h <- lapply(List, function(x) do.call("subset", list(x, s)))

  Filter(NROW, h)
}


D <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/m/master/k.csv", h = T) ## Dataset
L <- split(D, D$study.name) ; L[[1]] <- NULL   ## list by `study.name`

foo(L, type == 4)    ## subsets entries with `type == 4`. BUT how can function `foo` 
                     ## find and append entries with `control == TRUE` to its output?

foo(L, prof == 2)   # entries with `control == TRUE` are already present don't do anything!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can modify the function to

```
foo <- function(List, what){       ## The subsetting function

  s <- substitute(what) 

  h <- lapply(List, function(x) do.call("subset", list(x, s)))

  h1 <- Filter(NROW, h)
  nm1 <- names(which(!sapply(h1, function(x) any(x$control))))
  if(length(nm1) > 0) {
  h1[nm1]  <- Map(function(x, y) rbind(y, x[x$control, ]), List[nm1], h1[nm1])
  }
  h1

}

foo(L, type == 4) 
foo(L, prof == 2)
```